# Configuring flask with lighttpd

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm following the [flask documentation to deploy my Flask application over Lighttpd](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/fastcgi/#creating-a-fcgi-file).

It tells that we need to create a `.fcgi` file, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from yourapplication import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(application, bindAddress='/path/to/fcgi.sock').run()
```

My questions are :

1. I don't use the `from yourapplication import app` line in my flask app, but it works fine. Do I need that import statement?
2. Where do I find the `fcgi.sock` file on my Centos server?

Comment: If you don't use `app` then no matter if you imported it or not your code will work, in fact you are just running the server.You don't find `fcgi.sock` you just mention the path where you want it to be. Somewhere like `/tmp/yourapplication/fcgi.sock` the server will eventually create the file and place it to the path you just mentioned in your server configuration file.

Comment: @0decimal0: got it, so could I place it in the directory that has the file which I export as the `FLASK_APP` then?

Comment: You can , you just need to remember where?

Comment: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI